# Dict to JSON or Dataframe to JSON export yields no square brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Converting a dataframe to JSON or from dictionary to JSON, resulted in no luck for some reason no matter which parameter of orient was used (table or split or index or records).

code:

```
dataf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Objects", "Col1", "Col2"])   
dataf['Objects'] = ['Object1','Object2']
dataf['Col1']= ["1","2"]
dataf['Col2']= ["3","4"]

dataf.set_index('Objects', inplace = True)    

# dataf converted to dict 
dataf = dataf.to_dict(orient='index')
```

My output:

```
dataf
Out[199]: {'Object1': {'Col1': '1', 'Col2': '3'}, 'Object2': {'Col1': '2', 'Col2': '4'}}
```

Where 'Object1' and 'Object2' are keys  and where its correspoding values are  {'Col1': '1', 'Col2': '3'} where Col1 is key '1' is value and Col2 is key 3 is value

outp1 = json.dumps(dataf)

```
outp1
Out[225]: '{"Object1": {"Col1": "1", "Col2": "3"}, "Object2": {"Col1": "2", "Col2": "4"}}'
```

Desired output (Edited):

```
{
  "Object1": [{
        "Col1": "1",
        "Col2": "3"
      },
  {
  "Object2": [{
        "Col1": "2",
        "Col2": "4"
      }],
  }]
}
```

If I miss-typed the syntax of proper JSON here is the link to the picture: [link](https://postimg.cc/HVRWjsMh)
This is the format I'm looking to get when converting it to JSON.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that as a value for `Object1` you want a list containing a dictionary with `Col1` and `Col2`, as well as `Object3` and its columns?

Comment: Where does Object 3 comes from?

Comment: It's called nested dictionary I would say where Object1 and Object2 are the main keys in which there are 'columns' and those columns have information or values of them. The output describes it I guess?

Comment: "Expected/Desired output and additional example added (pseudo): " meaning that I just continued with the example how the output should look like. with the code and dataframe above just the first block should be exactly that way outputed, without further example of Object3 etc

Comment: What should be the output for the DataFrame in your input?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense to me based on your dataframe. Why just ignore Object 2?

Comment: Ecko, I think you are confused about how dictionaries work. Dictionaries, denoted by{}, are naturally able to store multiple key/value pairs. There is no need for a list, denoted by [], to be wrapped around the inner dictionary. The output you are already getting is correct.

Comment: Alright I've edited the code I got confused by trying to recplicate the dataframe and with it's outputs. Since the dataframe is big I have to know what belongs to what. Meaning that there are multiple "Objects" (Object1,Object2,Object3,Object4..etc). Initially it was just a column after conversion to dictionaries they become keys and in those keys other columns with its information are added. So I need to separate them like { "Object1":[{"Col1":"1"....},{"Object2":[{ "Col2" .... }]

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion  I see what you mean. To be perfectly honest I'm more confused with JSON type, since I'm not that familiar with it, how should it look like syntax wise. So there is no sense converting it or playing with the parameters or data conversion in order to get the desired output that I've stated lastly?  Basically, it's good as it is?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your goal is, but let me give you an example. Say you want to find the value for `Col2` of `Object2`. With the way Pandas did it, you'd just have to do `output["Object2"]["Col2"]`. With the way you're trying to do it, you'd have to do `output["Object1"][1]["Object2"][0]["Col2"]`. Which one do you think you want?

Comment: [link](https://postimg.cc/HVRWjsMh) 
If you check this picture, basically that format I'm looking for from the Dataframe that I've created (from dict -> JSON)

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion Why isn't it possible just either from Dataframe type to_json to get that format or from dictinary to JSON format. Instead I'm getting the output stated above, with no square brackets. That's confusing me the most, seems like I have to do something differently with the way my data is built?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what's going on. I'll write up an answer for you in a bit

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion Thanks would appreciate it. Excuse my mistakes in the initial description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go through a few ways of formatting your data and how useful they would be.

1. What you originally asked for in your question:

```
{
  "Object1": [{
        "Col1": "1",
        "Col2": "3"
      },
  {
  "Object2": [{
        "Col1": "2",
        "Col2": "4"
      }],
  }]
}
```

This is 100% wrong  for reasons I already went over in a comment. In order to access `Col2` of `Object2`, you'd have to do `output["Object1"][1]["Object2"][0]["Col2"]`. This makes absolutely no sense.

2.

```
{
  "Object1": [{
        "Col1": "1",
        "Col2": "3"
      }],
  {
  "Object2": [{
        "Col1": "2",
        "Col2": "4"
      }],
  }
}
```

This is slightly better, but still not really useful. Now in order to access `Col2` of `Object2`, you'd have to do `output["Object2"][0]["Col2"]`. What use does that extra `[0]` in the middle have? None.

3. What Pandas gave you

```
{
    'Object1': {
        'Col1': '1',
        'Col2': '3'
    },
    'Object2': {
        'Col1': '2',
        'Col2': '4'
    }
}
```

This is useful. Now, in order to access `Col2` of `Object2`, you just have to do `output["Object2"]["Col2"]`. This is a perfectly acceptable way of organizing the data.

4. What I think you're asking for

```
{
    'Objects': [
        {
            'name': 'Object1'
            'Col1': '1',
            'Col2': '3'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'Object2'
            'Col1': '2',
            'Col2': '4'
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on the link you put in the comments, it seems like this is your goal. The objects are stored in a list, and each list has a set of key/value pairs. Note that I converted `ObjectN` from a key to a value. This is because lists don't have key/value pairs.

5. A simpler version of 4

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Object1'
        'Col1': '1',
        'Col2': '3'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Object2'
        'Col1': '2',
        'Col2': '4'
    }
]
```

This is just as useful as 4, but easier to use. Instead of `output['Objects'][1]['Col2']`, you now just need `output[1]['Col2']`.

**So which one should you use?**

It depends on what you want to do with your data. If you want to be able to easily iterate through objects then you want 4/5. This is because they rely on lists, and iterating is exactly what lists are good for. On the other hand, if you mostly want to find the information for a single object without worrying about other objects then you want 3. Dictionaries are made for jumping to specific values.

If you want to find out how to convert from 3 to 4 or 5, I recommend asking another question or trying it yourself. It's not hard!